# How can I create a node test launch configuration?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, testing

I have some "node 18 test runner" tests written. I can run them with this command:

```
node --loader tsx --test tests/**/*.ts
```

I want to be able to debug the tests in vscode, so I figured I should have a `launch.json` configuration entry for that. But how do I do that?

This is what I tried:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--loader",
                "tsx",
                "--test",
                "--test-reporter=spec",
                "tests/**/*.ts"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        },
    ]
}
```

When I run this configuration, this is the executed command:

```
❯ node --loader tsx --test tests/**/*.ts cd /home/birger/someproject ; /usr/bin/env 'NODE_OPTIONS=--require /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.js --ins
pect-publish-uid=http' 'VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS={"inspectorIpc":"/tmp/node-cdp.165926-f285dca5-96.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"/home/birger/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node","o
nlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallback":"/tmp/node-debug-callback-4ea344155215e4e5"}' /home/birger/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node --loader tsx --test --test-reporter=spec tests/\*\*/\*
.ts
```

This is the output:

```
Could not find '/home/birger/someproject/cd'
Debugger attached.
Could not find '/home/birger/someproject/tests/**/*.ts'
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

The command `ls /home/birger/someproject/tests/` yields a list of 4 .ts files.

How can I write a vscode launch.json configuration to debug the node 18 test runner tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node version: v19.9.0

Project folder structure:

```bash
☁  node-test-runner  tree -L 4 -I 'node_modules'         
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── tests
│   └── modules
│       └── a.test.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

`tests/modules/a.test.ts`:

```
import test from 'node:test';
import assert from 'assert';

test('synchronous passing test', () => {
  assert.strictEqual(1, 1);
  const a = '123';
  debugger
});
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "test-runner",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test:vscode": "globstar -- node --loader ts-node/esm --test tests/**/*.test.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "globstar": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

`.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "test",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script",
        "test:vscode"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Click the "RUN AND DEBUG" arrow button, result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "zsh",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-c",
                "node --loader tsx --test --test-reporter=spec tests/**/*.ts",
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        },
    ]
}
```